# How to escape a character within a heading in org-mode?

Tags: org-mode, latex

Documenting this because I could not find an answer in stack exchange.

A heading such as this breaks during LaTeX export:

```
* MITRE ATT&CK
```

Rather than switching to a code-block, and loosing the folding and movement abilities of an org-mode heading, how do you escape the `&` inline?

Comment: This seems to be properly escape for LaTeX, at least as of Org version 9.1.14 in Emacs version 25.3.50 (actually Aquamacs 3.5 on a Mac)

Comment: `M-x org-version -> Org mode version 9.1.14 (9.1.14-9-g131531-elpaplus @ /Users/.../.emacs.d/elpa/org-plus-contrib-20181203/)` and `M-x emacs-version -> GNU Emacs 26.1 (build 1, x86_64-apple-darwin18.0.0, Carbon Version 158 AppKit 1671) of 2018-10-01` using emacs-mac port from 
Mitsuharu Yamamoto. Dunno why it didn't work either, works in text, just not headings. Just wanted to document the workaround.

Comment: I confirm this does work with org 9.1.14.

Comment: @glallen - Did you try substituting `&` with the [symbol](https://orgmode.org/worg/org-symbols.html)    `\amp`?

Answer (score 1):

One solution is to use `C-x 8 <RET>` or `M-x insert-char` to select the unicode character. This method works for LuaLaTeX and XeLaTeX when using `\usepackage{fontspec}`.

Another solution is to use inline code:

```
* MITRE @@latex: ATT\&CK@@
```

This works perfectly for LaTeX, but breaks HTML export, as the `@@latex: @@` block isn't exported.

Comment: The better solution is to investigate why *your* setup does this wrong while other people's setup does it right. FWIW, I cannot reproduce it either but I use a more recent version. Have you tried starting with `emacs -q`, thus bypassing your init file? If that works, then something is wrong with your init file, so that's where you concentrate.